# Positioning 2 elements (countdown timer and button) in row, side by side - they are not centered

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I have a problem with one of sections in my HTML code.

My idea is simply: one section made by 1 row, who is divided on 2 columns.

In left column i tried to put countodwn timer, and "submit" button in right column. They have to be side by side, and on equal distance in regards to each other; but there are some problems - they are on unequal distance and i am wondering how to fix it...

Also, when i test how draft of my site looks on mobile, parts of the clock do not stay together - they just move under each other.

Here is a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bc2e7y1n/).

What i am doing wrong?

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row align-items-center"><div class="col-6 mx-auto">    
<h3 style=" font-family: Open Sans; font-weight: light; font-size: 20px; color: 636363;letter-spacing: 1px; padding-left:110px;">Deadline:</h3>
<div id="clockdiv">
<div>   <span class="days"></span>
<div class="smalltext">Days</div>
</div>
<div>   <span class="hours"></span>
<div class="smalltext">Hours</div>
</div>
<div>   <span class="minutes"></span>
<div class="smalltext">Minutes</div>
</div>
<div>   <span class="seconds"></span>
<div class="smalltext">Seconds</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="col-6 mx-auto">
<button class="button button1" style="width: 300px; height: 100px;">Submit</button>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

And CSS:

```
  #clockdiv{
    font-family: Open Sans;
    color: #ffffff;
    display: inline-block;
    font-weight: 100;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 30px;
  }

  #clockdiv > div{
    padding: 0px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    background: #fffff;
    display: inline-block;
  }

  #clockdiv div > span{
    padding: 15px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    background: #000;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;

  }

  .smalltext{
    padding-top: 5px;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #000;
    position: relative;

  }

  .button {
    background-color: #fff; 
    border: none;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none; 
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: 'Open Sans';
    margin: 4px 2px;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.4s; 
    transition-duration: 0.4s;
    cursor: pointer;
  }

  .button1 {
    background-color: white; 
    color: #000; 
    border: 2px solid #000;

  }

  .button1:hover {
    background-color: #fff;
    color: white;
```

Comment: Hi @aegis999, it might help if you read Stack Overflow's guide on [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You should also avoid asking multiple questions in a single question, like you have here. It would also be much more helpful if you had a picture of your code, or used a service like [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) to help us visualize your problem.

Comment: Load the `<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">`, See [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/snb45kte/)

Comment: Thank you!

At this moment, countdown timer and button are side by side  but they seems not centered in regards to vertical axis and previous section above them.

Draft maybe help you to visualize problem: http://prntscr.com/mb27xu

I am wondering how to make them  in center of their collumns (section is made of row divided on 2 collumns).